# Conditionally truncating a filename to a max length without damaging the file extension

Tags: php, php5

Yes, I'm bad at conditionals. I don't use them so much and I feel a bit lost with them. How would you (if possible) refactor or change this little piece of code?

**Second improved version**:

```
$MAX_FNAME_LEN   = 255;
$clientFilename  = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
$clientExtension = $this->file->guessExtension();

// Assume a failure in reading client filename
$defFilename = $defRandFilename = uniqid('fid_', true);

if(!is_null($clientFilename))
{
    $clientFilenameLength = strlen($clientFilename);
    $hasClientExtension   = !is_null($clientExtension);

    $removeFromEnd = $hasClientExtension ? - (1 + strlen($clientExtension)) : 0;
    $appendAtEnd   = $hasClientExtension ? ".$clientExtension" : '';

    if($clientFilenameLength > $MAX_FNAME_LEN) // Truncate original filename
    {
        $excessFromEnd = $MAX_FNAME_LEN - $clientFilenameLength - $removeFromEnd;
        $defFilename   = substr($clientFilename, 0, $excess) . $appendAtEnd;
    }
    else
        $defFilename  = $clientFilename; // User original filename

    if(strlen($defRandFilename) + abs($removeFromEnd) > $MAX_FNAME_LEN) // Truncate sanitized
        $defRandFilename = substr($defRandFilename, 0, $removeFromEnd) . $appendAtEnd;
    else
        $defRandFilename .= $appendAtEnd; // Use sanitized plus extension
}
```

Comment: is this php?  wow, i've never used endif; before, I've always traditionally used { braces and if else statements.  What are the benefits to this approach?  (this is just a general review comment really)

Comment: @dreza yes, PHP. I like "explicit end" cause it clearly states where conditional/loop ends, instead of having too much `}}}}`. I'll do all the time :)

Comment: @dreza It’s pretty much discouraged in normal code. It can be tremendously helpful when mixed with a lot of HTML though. When using PHP to create templates, I invariably use this style (otherwise, the braces).

Comment: Cheers guys, good to know about this feature of PHP

Comment: Gremo, I’ve rolled back your edit because it changed the question completely and led to confusion (see showerhead’s answer and my comment below that). If you want to show your code progress, either *add* the new code in the question instead of replacing the old code, or ask a new question if the scope has changed noticeably.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you're right, my bad. Thanks.

Comment: This question title might be one of the worst titles on CodeReview.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes, after 8 years, I agree.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question so that this page can be more easily searched for. @gremo

Comment: @mickmackusa no more the worst title on CodeReview :)

Comment: Some sample input strings and desired outputs would complete your question and make it upvote-worthy by providing context. @gremo  Yes, this is an old question.  Yes, I intend to post a review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't really agree with Konrad on a couple of points. First, `$clientFilenameLength`, while a bit far from where it is actually used and a bit lengthy for such a simple variable name, is not unnecessary. This variable prevents you from having to call a function, `strlen()`, twice on the same information. Its better to only have to run it once, and therefore the variable is necessary. Even if you only used that variable once, it would still be ok because sometimes it can enhance legibility or efficiency. This is especially the case when defining parameters for a for or while loop, because assigning functions as parameters in them will cause those functions to be called on every iteration, which is much less efficient than assigning a variable beforehand instead.

Again, I have to disagree with Konrad. "255" is not a magic constant. First of all, because magic constants, at least in PHP, define constants that are available in every script without you needing to do anything special to get them, such as the file name `__FILE__`. What I think he meant to say is magic number, but even then, this can't be considered a magic number because you did indeed define it before using it. If however you just did something like the following, then THAT would have been considered a magic number. What you have is fine.

```
if( $clientFilenameLength > 255 ) {//this is a magic number
```

Why not `isset()` instead of `! is_null()`? `isset()` has the added benefit of also checking for a null value and means you don't have to use the "not" syntax.

```
if( isset( $clientFilename ) ) {
    $hasClientExtension = isset( $clientExtension );
```

Make sure you use the proper variables! You've created an `$excessFromEnd` variable and then use `$excess` instead, so this wont work. This is why long variable names aren't always good. Be descriptive, but not excessive. God, I'm full of puns today, first lengthy then excessive :) Don't worry, I'll leave shortly. Speaking of names, all-caps separated by underscores should only really be used for constants, which `$MAX_FNAME_LEN` can, and probably should, be.

Subtracting a negative, at least if I remember highschool well enough, results in addition, so why not just make `$removeFromEnd` positive and add it? This will also mean that you can remove that `abs()` function.

```
$removeFromEnd = $hasClientExtension ? 1 + strlen($clientExtension) : 0;
//rest of code
$excessFromEnd = $MAX_FNAME_LEN - ( $clientFilenameLength + $removeFromEnd );
//rest of code
if( strlen( $defRandFilename ) + $removeFromEnd > $MAX_FNAME_LEN ) {
```

Always use braces! For languages, such as Python, that don't use braces, this is fine. But with PHP, even though they allow it, this is bad. PHP even agrees this is bad as it can cause issues with your code. Another good reason is to enhance legibility. I'm pretty sure this is similar for a lot of people, but I always expect the braces. So when I'm reading some code and it doesn't have them I have to go back to the beginning because when I got to the end the braces didn't match up. I don't always believe indentation, especially on CR, because sometimes its lost in the transfer process. It's just two little characters but they do so much.

```
else {
    $defFilename  = $clientFilename; // User original filename
}
```

Wow, just noticed this, and that should be a flag right there. Don't assign a variable to a variable you are just defining! They are hard to spot, and therefore hard to debug. As I just pointed out, I JUST found this while I was nearing the end of your script when I found `$defRandFilename` and was trying to figure out where it came from (answer: the beginning of the script). I had to use my IDE's highlighting to help me. If you need a copy of a variable, make one after you've made the original. But, from what I can tell from your code, this is just unnecessary. Just remove `$defFilename` here, you have it being reassigned no matter what later and you never use it before that. Actually, you just never really use it at all. You define `$defFilename` but its never used after that, I'm assuming because this is only partial code, but figured I'd point it out just in case.

```
$defFilename = $defRandFilename = uniqid('fid_', true);// this === bad
```

Alright, so if I'm reading this right, you just want to create a filename with a maximum of 255 characters, including extension. There is a problem. You are not comparing both the filename length AND extension length to the maximum allowed. At least not for `$defFilename`. You do, however, do it for `$defRandFilename`, but for `$defFilename` you are just comparing the filename's length. When you create the `$removeFromEnd` variable, you add the clause for the extension being removed as well, but you don't ever check it. BTW: What is the purpose of having both `$defFilename` AND `$defRandFilename`?

Now, you were asking for an easier way to do this. You could just use `substr()` from the beginning. If the length parameter passed to `substr()` is larger than the length of the supplied string it will only go to the original string's length, with no out of bounds errors or anything. So....

```
if( isset( $clientFilename ) ) {
    $newFilename = substr( $clientFilename, 0, $MAX_FNAME_LEN - strlen( $clientExtension ) );
    $newFilename .= $clientExtension;
}
```

I hope that's what you were looking for, and I hope the rest helps too :) The best advice I can give you right now is to make sure you define your variables close to where they are actually going to be used, rather than four or five lines away, or multiple indentations away. This was the biggest issue I had with reading this code. Well that and the braces. Good luck!

Comment: Magic number – yes. However, OP edited his post. In the original version he *did* use a magic number without defining a constant/variable. As for the redundant variable `$clientFilenameLength`: you claim that it’s good because it removes a redundant call to `strlen`. But have a look at my code: there is no redundant call.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I apologize if that's the case, I don't remember seeing an edited tag. Its been more than a week, and my memory is horrible. As for the variable, that's not the only reason I gave. However, yes, in your code it is unnecessary. I don't know if I just didn't notice, or what. Mostly I just try focusing on the OP's code rather than answers that already exist. I read them to make sure I'm not repeating them, but more or less I skim and leave it to the OP to read them fully and glean the best information.

Answer (score 3):

Use early exit: reverse the null-checking conditional and return.

```
if(is_null($clientFilename))
    return;
```

If your code isn’t in a function, *change that*.

Next, use consistent indentation for the `else`: it belongs on the same level as the `if`, *not* as the content of the `if`.

I’d also encourage you to follow general usage in PHP, i.e. to use the braced `if` style even though I agree with you that the other style is fundamentally more readable.

I’d also get rid of unnecessary variables such as `$clientFilenameLength`, and of magic constants (`255`). And as a small clean-up, use string interpolation instead of concatenation where it makes sense.

That leaves us with:

```
define('MAX_LENGTH', 255);
$clientFilename  = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
$clientExtension = $this->file->guessExtension();

// Assume a failure in reading client filename
$defFilename = $defRandFilename = uniqid('fid_', true);

if(is_null($clientFilename))
    return;

// Remove strlen($clientExtension) + 1 chars from the end
$hasClientExtension = !is_null($clientExtension);
$removeFromEnd = $hasClientExtension ? 1 + strlen($clientExtension) : 0;
$appendAtEnd = $hasClientExtension ? ".$clientExtension" : '';

if(strlen($clientFilename) > MAX_LENGTH)
    $defFilename = substr($clientFilename, 0, -$removeFromEnd) . $appendAtEnd;
else
    // User original upload name
    $defFilename  = $clientFilename;

if(strlen($defRandFilename) + $removeFromEnd > MAX_LENGTH) 
    $defRandFilename = substr($defRandFilename, 0, -$removeFromEnd) . $appendAtEnd;
else
    // Use random file name plus .ext
    $defRandFilename .= $appendAtEnd;
```

But this code probably doesn’t do what you want: the whole check for `strlen($clientFilename)` is a red herring because the result will *not* be truncated. It will remove (a string of the length of) the client extension, and subsequently replace it. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Can't use early check (i usually do early check/exit) because this is part of a function. And yes, you're right, this is not the intended behavior. I should remove `strlen($clientFilename) - MAX_LENGTH + strlen($appendAtEnd)`, if i'm right.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who "is bad at conditionals", the good news is that this script can be sensibly written with only one conditional.  I am electing to use a ternary expression in my custom function -- this avoids all of the debate around preferred control structure syntax.

1. If the filename has length, use that string (doesn't matter if it is an empty string or null or false). Otherwise generate the random prefixed string.
2. Prepend a dot to the extension value.  By unconditionally trimming the dots from the right side of the string, the prepended dot will be removed.  This spares having to writing a condition and saving the extension length to a variable.
3. Unconditionally truncate the filename before appending the extension.

This helper function has default values for every parameter so its utility is maximized for your application.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/F5p5b))

```
function prepareClientFilename($filename = '', $extension = '', $maxLength = 255) {
    $filename = strlen($filename) ? $filename : uniqid('fid_', true);
    $extension = rtrim(".{$extension}" , '.');
    return substr($filename, 0, $maxLength - strlen($extension)) . $extension;
}

$tests = [
    prepareClientFilename('this_is_a_string', 'txt'),
    prepareClientFilename(str_repeat(implode(range('a','z')), 9), 'pdf'),
    prepareClientFilename(str_repeat(implode(range('a','z')), 10), ''),
    prepareClientFilename(str_repeat(implode(range('a','z')), 10), 'csv'),
    prepareClientFilename('', 'jpeg', 10),
    prepareClientFilename('', 'mp4'),
    prepareClientFilename(),
];

var_export(array_combine($tests, array_map('strlen', $tests)));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'this_is_a_string.txt' => 20,
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.pdf' => 238,
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstu' => 255,
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopq.csv' => 255,
  'fid_5.jpeg' => 10,
  'fid_5e610132001487.17408713.mp4' => 31,
  'fid_5e6101320014a8.21403474' => 27,
)
```